# Community Builder - Embedded Visualforce Page does not display

Tags: lightning, visualforce-component, community-builder

I'm building a Lightning Community. When I add a Visualforce Page Component within the Builder, it displays correctly:

[image: Lightning Community Builder]

But when I publish changes and access the community, it does not:

[image: View in Chrome accessing the community on the external URL]

No errors are showing up in the browser console. The Visualforce Page Component simply does not get rendered, no matter the content of the page itself.

As far as I can see, the page meets all requirements listed on https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5. It is not a Cache problem, because any other changes are applied in the browser view and I'm using Chrome's incognito mode with the option "Disable Cache" enabled. I also tried to embed this component on a new page with identical results.

Can someone reproduce this behavior, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the community user profile have security access to the VF page and its component controller?

Comment: @cropredy No, it had not! Enabled and now is working fine. Thanks! Please add an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Community User's Profile (Site's guest user profile or the profile used for an authenticated community user) needs to be granted access to

- The VF page

Granting such access also grants access to the page's VF component(s) and their associated controller(s). See [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_page_level_security.htm&type=5)